# how to convert xml document parsed by org.dom4j.io.SAXReader into a visual Swing tree?

Tags: java, xml, jtree, dom4j, treemodel

I have parsed an xml document using **org.dom4j.io.SAXReader**, is it possible to feed this into **javax.swing.tree.TreeModel** and generate a dynamically changing visual Swing *JTree*?

For example, when I programmaticaly add or delete nodes, I want the Swing *JTree* to reflect teh changes immediately.

How can I achieve this, and is there a better suggestion to using dom4j ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [BranchTreeNode](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/dom4j/swing/BranchTreeNode.html). I think this should help.

Comment: that appears to be something I am looking for. It would be nice if I could find some examples for it.